# "UPDATE `produit` SET `stock`=stock-$qt"

Tags: php

i need your help , I am programming a script about management of stock , But i find this problem , for example , i have 5 product , And each product has in stock 5 quantity, when i want to Set that the Product number 1 sold out once , all other product removed One quantity too  , what can i do , and Thank you
This is the code :

```
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `produit` SET `stock`=stock-$qt") or 
    die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Please guys i need help

Comment: What for $totalstock variable is using?
Why are you doing $totalstock+=$res['stock']; twice?
And how are you updating stock?

Comment: sorry i add the not correct code , i edite the poste now , please see the real code , and thanks for your Reply

Comment: You are missing a `where` clause in your update statement to limit the rows that get updated.

Answer (score -1):

```
$id = $res['id'] //id (or other primary key) of a product what you want to update 
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `produit` SET `stock`=stock-$qt WHERE 'id'=$id") or 
die(mysqli_error($con));
```